# Compares 2 values in Spring Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, https

I am trying to query and compare 2 values from Mysql table using Spring framework. I want to take 2 values from these 2 tables and compare if they are the same then the code below will be executed.
Such as:

```
   If (...) {
   System.out.println ("success");
     }
```

Database:
Table User:
ID = 1
Name = John

Table Address:
ID = 1;
Name = America

This is just a mock code. In my code there is using Session (HttpServlet). Like the code above example, I want to get 2 ID values from the User table and Adrress compare them with each other. So is there any way to get the ID value of someone named John when he logs in to the system and compare it with the ID value of the above address? I used the Select statement and I also tried the request from the Session but I all failed. Is there any way to help me? Thanks

Comment: don't show 'mock code', show the actual code you 've tried. How and where are you trying to compare the values? In java code, or in an sql statement?

Comment: `Select 1 From User u, Address a Where u.name = :name and a.name = :aName and u.id = a.id` probably something like that.